# Range query over a Binary Search Tree in Prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-search-tree

I know how to perform a range query over a BST in procedural way (that is, in C++, Java and so on) but I find it difficult to convert into Prolog language.

The procedural way should be like:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-bst-keys-in-the-given-range/

any hint how to convert it into Prolog paradigma?

thanks a lot to everybody

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do the very same you do in C++ or Java.
There are *very* high chances you'll got the *right* result, assuming that (in C++, to say), you wrote the *minimal* code required. That account usually for a recursive definition: something like

```
// pseudocode - Elem must implement operator<
struct BST<Elem> {
  bool find(const Elem e) { return find(root, e) }
private:
  bool find(Node n, Elem e) {
    if (!n) return false;
    if (n.payload() == e) return true;
    return n.payload() < e ? find(n.left) : find(n.right);
  }
}
```

The same search can be written manually unfolding the stack, by means of (duh) stack, then iterating

```
stack<Node> stack; stack.push(root);
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
  Node n = stack.pop();
  // check found, return true
  // push left or right...
}
```

In Prolog the stack is 'embedded' in the language: just state what's the solution 'form': assuming a tree like `t(Payload, Left, Right)` with a default like `t(0,-,-)` you can do

```
% note: untested
bst(t(Payload,_,_), Payload). % found
bst(t(Payload,L,R), Sought) :- Sought @< Payload -> bst(L, Sought) ; bst(R, Sought).
```

A note on C++: I've uploaded on github (at [loqt](http://capellic.github.io/loqt/)) an example of a declarative, non intrusive C++ interface on a *raw* pointer model (Agraph_t* and friends). With that interface, very simple to implement now that we have lambda in C++:

```
// live code here
void lqXDotScene::dump(QString m) const {
    qDebug() << m;
    cg->depth_first([&](Gp t) { qDebug() << "graph" << gvname(t) << CVP(find_graph(t)); });
    qDebug() << "nodes";
    cg->for_nodes([&](Np n) {
        qDebug() << "node" << gvname(n) << CVP(find_node(n));
        cg->for_edges_out(n, [&](Ep e) {
            qDebug() << "edge" << gvname(e) << CVP(find_edge(e)) << "to" << gvname(e->node) << CVP(find_node(e->node));
        });
    });
}
```

the line

```
    cg->depth_first([&](Gp t) { qDebug() << "graph" << gvname(t) << CVP(find_graph(t));
```

does a *full* visit. find_graph, find_ etc are *member* function: lambda it's *very* powerful.

Answer (score 2):

The declarative description from the site you cite can be directly translated to Prolog:

1) If *key* is greater than *k1*, then recursively call in left subtree.

Prolog translation:

```
bst(tree(Key, Left, Right), K1, K2, Value) :-
        Key > K1,
        bst(Left, K1, K2, Value).
```

2) If *key* is in range, then print the key.

We do not use impure predicates like "print", because they are not reversible. Instead, we use Prolog to report bindings on the toplevel for us:

```
bst(tree(Key, _, _), K1, K2, Key) :- between(K1, K2, Key).
```

3) If *key* is smaller than *k2*, then recursively call in right subtree.

I leave this as an exercise.

The query

`?- bst(Tree, K1, K2, Value).`

will yield on backtracking bindings for `Value` that are in the given range.

If you use constraints, you can use this predicate in all directions and also *generate* trees that contain a value.

Comment: It worked greatly .. but what about If I want to have all whole answer in one step in an output list? This solutions retrieves results one by one.

Comment: It is easy to collect all solutions in Prolog: Use an all-solutions predicate like `setof/3`.